# Selecting more than one non adjacent categories in komento

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.2

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, I searched through everything I could find, but did not find an answer :(

Basically what I want to do is to include komento (joomla extension) in two categories that do not lie above/below one another, here is what it looks like on the backend:

```
.| Category 1

.| Category 2

.| Category 3
```

I want to include komento in category 1 and 3, however, I somehow can´t only select category 1 and 3, I always have to select category 2 as well. How can I only select category 1 & 3?

This must be something really simple that I seem to be missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be really simple, all you need to do is hold down the ctrl key for windows or the cmd key for mac and click on the category that you would like to select.